# How to monitor bandwidth usage of my application?

Tags: c#, silverlight, sockets, network-programming

I want to monitor bandwidth usage of my silverlight application. My silverlight application  sends and receive data through the net.

Based on my research,

1. pcap.net and sharppcap can capture packet. By using filtering, I can know bandwidth usage of my application
2. Use networkinterface class [NetworkInterface Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

   The problem is, this class is unavailable in silverlight. Even if it does, Im not sure if I can get bandwidth usage for specific application.
3. Silverlight socket. While i can send small packets and build bandwidth counter around it, i found that sending one large data fares better than sending multiple small data. Send one large data yield bigger bandwidth. I did try minimize calls between sending, yet the results still the same.

Any advice and thoughts?